# Is it possible to launch a song into the ipod app from another app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, url-scheme

I am working in an app. According to my requirement, I am trying to launch a song or a playlist from the app that i am making, into the ipod app, i know i can open this with:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"music:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

but im wondering if it is posible to use something like this.

```
@"music://aSong";
```

or even better

```
`@"music://aPlayList";`
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing, but don't believe it's possible. The closest you can get is to use a `UIDocumentInteractionController`. It allows you to export a file to a compatible app based on a UTI ([List of available UTI's here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)). I implemented it using the "public.mpeg-4-audio" UTI, and it didn't show me Music-- only iMovie, djay, and Dropbox. There are many other apps that can handle music files I'm sure, but these are ones that I have. Music should have showed up there. I tried djay's exporting options only to find the same two apps: iMovie and Dropbox.

The other thing you can do, although it's a PITA for your users, is to set the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key in your Info.plist to `YES`. This will allow your users to: Select your device in iTunes, choose the Apps tab, and scroll down to File Sharing, select the app and retrieve your files.

If you are interested in implementing `UIDocumentInteractionController`, it works like this:

```
// set your audioFilepath first
// and declare UIDocumentInteractionController as a property of your view controller
self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilepath]];
self.documentController.UTI = @"public.mpeg-4-audio"; // kUTTypeMPEG4Audio
[self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765, the method varies somewhat depending on what exactly you want to do.

If you just want to use a link, this is the guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iTunesLinks/iTunesLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH3-SW1

To show an album for example, this should work:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewAlbum?i=156093464&id=156093462&s=143441";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: i read the apple documentation but i couldn't found  what im looking for, i know is posible because when you select a bought song with the itunes store, there is an option "reproduce" and redirects to the music app and starts reproducing..

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).